# Gradle: Create a dependency module with a custom remote artifact URL

Tags: gradle

I'd like my build configuration to use traditional repository management (group, version resolution, etc) but also not have my build rely on Maven or Ivy descriptor files.

I am attempting to do this with a ClientModule in Gradle. The documentation states this is possible by declaring the module's meta data in the build file.

http://www.gradle.org/docs/1.7/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:client_module_dependencies

This is what I have:

```
repositories {
    //no external repos
}

dependencies {
    runtime module("org.lessjs:lessjs:1.4.1") {
        transitive = true
        artifact {
            type = "js"
            name = "lessjs"
            url = "https://raw.github.com/less/less.js/master/dist/less-1.4.1.min.js"
        }
    }

    runtime module("org.jquery:jquery:1.10.1") {
        transitive = true
        artifact {
            type = "js"
            name = "jquery"
            url=  "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"
        }
    }
}
```

I would like the artifacts downloaded from the URLs specified so that the javascript files are placed in the local repository.  However I encounter an unresolved dependency error for the two modules.

How can I make this work? Do I need to implement a new type of ArtifactRespository to resolve this custom dependency scheme?

UPDATE: I've encountered WebJars (http://www.webjars.org/) which is interesting for my particular javascript dependencies, but I'd like to know how to do this without a Maven/Ivy repo if possible.

UPDATE PART 2: It appears Gradle does not support this, even though it claims Ivy support. I was able to make this work with Gant/Ivy using a local ivy module file and a custom URL that points to remote artifacts and downloads the files to the local cache. You can do this with an arbitrary file, such as a Javascript file.

Comment: Gradle supports Ivy repositories, not Ivy per se.

Comment: There is a good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34327202/2873507

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this use of `artifact.url` is really implemented; I've never seen it used in a build. Gradle's dependency resolution mechanism is geared towards interacting with Maven and Ivy repositories. As far as I know, it isn't a viable choice for downloading from arbitrary URLs.

Comment: It appears you can configure a non-standard URL in Ivy, so I was wondering if there was a way to trigger that behavior via Gradle.

http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/artifact.html

Comment: It's probably a leftover from Gradle's Ivy heritage. I don't think it can be made to work.

Comment: Okay, so to make this work with local meta-data but remote artifacts, then I need to use a local Ivy repo with a custom Ivy descriptor that refers to the remote artifact. Is that the best route at this point?

Comment: Whether or not you use client-module dependencies, you can't use an arbitrary download URL. The URL is constructed from the module ID, group ID, version, and in the case of an Ivy repository, also the artifact pattern. For something like JQuery, you'll probably have to publish it to your Ivy/Maven repo first, and then you can reference it in the usual way.

Comment: I'd prefer my build system to be portable without maintaining a repository while also getting the latest files. The source files should come from their respective project URLs. You are correct about the implementation... Gradle doesn't use Ivy to resolve the artifacts, but instead does the work and it does not implement this concept of non-local artfifacts. Is it possible to write a custom adapter in the ivyservice package to somehow patch this feature?