# How are Ivy custom layouts interpreted by Gradle?

Tags: gradle, ivy

I have declared a custom ivy repository layout:

```
repositories {
    ivy {
        url "https://myurl.com/root/"
        layout 'pattern', {
             artifact "[organisation]/[name]-[version].[ext]"
        }
    }
}
```

and then I declare a dependency:

```
dependencies {
   compile 'mygroup:myartifact:0.1@zip'
}
```

but for some reason it doesn't work, Gradle doesn't find the dependency, and it seems to look in the wrong place: `https://myurl.com/root/mygroup/[name]-[version].zip`

I have also tried doing fancy things such as the following:

```
dependencies {
   compile module ('mygroup:myartifact:0.1@zip') {
      artifact {
         name = 'myartifact'
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

but it doesn't work either.

How to correctly define the layout pattern so that it be well interpreted by Gradle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify a dependency with `'<group>:<artifact>:<version>(@<ext>)'`, Gradle applies the following mapping to the pattern :

- `<group>` replaces `[organisation]`
- `<artifact>` replaces `[module]`
- `<version>` replaces `[revision]`
- `<ext>` replaces `[ext]`

So in your case, your pattern should look like:

```
artifact "[organisation]/[module]-[revision].[ext]"
```

*Credit to @RaGe for [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34327202/2873507)*