# Is it possible to extract nuget artifacts in gradle?

Tags: gradle, nuget, repository

I need to import an artifact from a nuget repository in my gradle project. I've tried doing the following:

1. Adding the repository in the gradle.build file:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://artifactory.mycompany.tools/artifactory/nuget-repo/" }
  }
```

2. Adding the dependency:

```
  implementation("library:artifact:version")
```

But this does now work, because gradle is expecting a POM inside the repo. The artifact only contains a .nupkg file.

Comment: This should be possible using an Ivy repository with a suitable pattern. This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34327202/4161471